# How to use grunt changelog?

Tags: git, gruntjs

I'm trying to use [grunt-conventional-changelog](https://github.com/btford/grunt-conventional-changelog) to automatically generate a CHANGELOG.md. 
I tagged my release like this:

```
>git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "Iteartion 0 release, v0.0.1"
```

How should I commit my changes so that grunt includes Features, Build, Bugfixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [readme](https://github.com/btford/grunt-conventional-changelog):

> Generate a changelog from git metadata, using [these](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QrDFcIiPjSLDn3EL15IJygNPiHORgU1_OOAqWjiDU5Y/edit) conventions.

Comment: Oops. I totally missed that link. Thank you

Comment: @sgimeno Do you  have a public project I could take a look at? I'm trying to use the same plugin but not having any success